# Select2 tagging: add custom text behind new tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, tagging

I'm using the [select2 tagging feature](https://select2.org/tagging). Is there an easy way to add a custom text behind a new tag. My intention is, that the user knows that he/she will add the tag.

The result should look something like that eg. in examle of color names, there it could say "new color" after a new tag:

[image: add tag custom text eg new color]

```js
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
  tags: true
});
```

```css
select, pre {
  display: inline-block;
}

.js-example-tags {
  width: 256px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-example-tags">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option>purple</option>
</select> <pre><== Type new tag into search and click enter</pre>
```

Comment: Did you check this in the docs? https://select2.org/tagging#tag-properties

Comment: your sample doesnt show how you add a new tag from your selection

Comment: @Frenchy just type in a new color and hit enter or click in the selection list on it. As this is not really intuitive, I would like to add some text eg. "add new color"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understant your logic, you could try this:

```js
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
  tags: true,
  createTag:newtag,
  matcher: matchCustom,
});

function newtag(params, data){
    var term = $.trim(params.term);
    if (term === '') {
      return null;
    }
      return {
      id: term,
      text: term + " (New color)",
      newTag: true // add additional parameters
    }
}

function matchCustom(params, data) {
    // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
      return data;
    }

    // Do not display the item if there is no 'text' property
    if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
      return null;
    }
    
   // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
    return null;
}
```

```css
select, pre {
  display: inline-block;
}

.js-example-tags {
  width: 256px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-example-tags">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option>purple</option>

</select> <pre><== Type new tag into search and click enter</pre>
```

Comment: The only improvement would be that the selected tag doesn't show "new color" anymore. My intention was to make it clear to the user, that he has to select the new tag (either by pressing enter or by clicking it).

Comment: you mean yu dont want (new color) in future selection after added?